# Which linters are supported by nano?

Tags: nano

In my `latex.nanorc` file, I have the following instructions:

```
syntax "LaTeX" "\.(la)?tex$"
linter lacheck
```

However, when I press the keyboard shortcut to run the linter, I get an error message `La commande « lacheck » n'a produit aucune ligne analysable` (i.e  `The 'lacheck' command did not produce any analysable lines` in English).

When I run `lacheck` by its own on my tex file it produces this output:

```
"article.tex", line 21: missing `\ ' after "e.g.".
```

My guess is that the format of the message is not understood by nano (version 5.8).
Is there a standard protocol a linter must comply to in order to be recognised by nano?

Comment: When I run `lacheck` by its own on my tex file it produces `"article.tex", line 21: missing \`\ ' after "e.g."`. My guess is that the format of the message is not understood by nano

Comment: See also: `extendsyntax` in [the nano docs](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html#Syntax-Highlighting): "This allows you to add a new ... linter ... command to an already defined syntax"

Comment: `extendsyntax` is just a way to add an instruction to an already defined syntax (for example by an included file) but I'm defining my own syntax from scratch for LaTeX, `extendsyntax` is irrelevant to me. And since nano refers to `lacheck` in its error message, my instruction is correctly taken into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a de facto standard format for compiler or linter error messages, which is the same format as `grep -n`: `FILE_NAME:LINE_NUMBER:MESSAGE`. Experimentally, nano supports that. I haven't researched if it supports any other format, but in any case it doesn't support lacheck's format.

You can define a wrapper to the lacheck command that rewrites its messages in the standard format, and tell nano to invoke that wrapper instead of invoking lacheck directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o pipefail
lacheck "$@" 2>&1 | sed 's/^"\([^"]*\)", line /\1:/'
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!